# Is there any use for the Apple Wallet app in India?

Tags: iphone, wallet, apple-pay

I can see the Apple Wallet app and the supported app list shows apps such as Paytm, Zomato, etc.

Is there anything that can be actually done with the Apple Wallet app for indian users?

I know India does not have Apple Pay support, at least can we use the Wallet app to safely store debit card credentials, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely and securely use the Wallet app to store your credit card information, even if you never use it for Apple Pay.